# eventDrop time changes everytime the event is dropped

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using full calendar and I'm trying to update an event using event drop but as I drop the event the time changes and sometimes the date expands like from two dates it will become three dates vice versa.

Comment: This is not the normal behaviour. Perhaps you have made some mistake but we can't tell what it is without seeing some examples of code and data. Please provide a [mre] of the issue. Thanks.